# Parachain missed blocks due to relay wrong announcement?

Tags: parachain, error, block-production

On February 20, 2023 around 22:08 UTC, Shiden block production has been hurt and almost stopped during 40 minutes.A lot of collators were missing blocks for no apparent reason.

[image: Shiden block rate]Examples of blocks that have been missed by several collators:

- https://shiden.subscan.io/block/3428714
- https://shiden.subscan.io/block/3428720

Location and hardware specs of the collators are not the source of the error, we checked the logs from different collators with correct specs / location.

Generally on the relay side, a lot of these messages are issued.

```
[Relaychain] Missing block weight for new head. Skipping chain. hash=0x942d17da9ac8ce3634542da34757d4a66cfed6d27e79aed7d0857828f433caf0
```

The parachain was build with a previous version of relay, we have now upgraded to latest and monitoring for the next time it may happen.

### Timeline of errors

**22:09 UTC** - On 1st round of blocks missed by our collators 1 and 2

Collator 1
[image: logs]

Noticeable messages

```
2023-02-20 22:09:28 [Parachain] Failed to create inherent data providers. error="Failed to create parachain inherent"
2023-02-20 22:09:28 [Parachain] Cannot obtain the hrmp ingress channel. relay_parent=0x4c7d1661f220b49c3c7015810cc01ce2d336ee555c9191f74e58a234092768f1 error=BlockchainError(UnknownBlock("State already discarded for 0x4c7d1661f220b49c3c7015810cc01ce2d336ee555c9191f74e58a234092768f1"))
```

Collator 2 (next one in Aura selection) got no message and didn't even try to enter block production process, but at the exact time of if supposed to produce the block:

```
2023-02-20 22:09:36 [Relaychain] Missing block weight for new head. Skipping chain. hash=0x942d17da9ac8ce3634542da34757d4a66cfed6d27e79aed7d0857828f433caf0
```

**22:20 UTC** - another round of blocks missed

Collator 1
[image]

Collator 2
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed report! We are looking into it. Please keep us posted on new discoveries on your end!

Comment: This issue may be related: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6758

Comment: Yes it is related to this issue thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been discussed & closed here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6758